# SQL Server 2014 error: Msg 7738, Level 16, State 2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014-express

Is SQL Server Express edition (2014) not supporting compression at all ?
(Is it necessary to upgrade to enterprise edition)

Comment: [Features Supported by the Editions of SQL Server 2014](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/partnercenter/cc645993(v=sql.120).aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Express Edition, you need SQL Server 2016 SP1 or later to support data compression. In earlier versions, you need Enterprise (or Developer for testing). The documentation below detail the features that may vary by SQL Server version and edition:

[SQL Server 2014 Features by Edition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/partnercenter/cc645993(v=sql.120).aspx)

[SQL Server 2016 Features by Edition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-2016)

[SQL Server 2017 Features by Edition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-2017)